# Javascript popup window in background after userinteract

Tags: javascript, popup

I want to open a little popup after clicking on a button.This Popup should open in the background.

This is my Code

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var newWindow = $this.open('/popup',"MyTitle", "width=600,height=400,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,location=no");
        newWindow.blur();
        this.window.focus();
    }, false);
```

What is my mistake? Why does it not open in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `window.focus();` instead of `this.window.focus();` ? I'm unsure if this will work as most browsers it causes security issues. Popunders aren't popular!

Comment: yes i tried a lot of diffrent solutions but none of these did work